# AKS Restrict Access to APIs

Tags: .net, microservices, azure-aks

We have Angular application hosted in AKS.
We also have additional five .NET 6 services hosted in AKS.

We would like to allow access to APIs only from the website service.
We do not want users to access directly APIs without using website.

Is there anyway to configure this using load balancer or ingress?

Comment: Your angular app hosted on AKS is just static assets that are executed by the user's browser. Restricting bot access is a tough problem. AWS WAF and services like cloudflare make an attempt, but not sure what options are available in azure.

Comment: Do APIs services need to be publicly available outside of your AKS cluster (other than communicating with the Angular app? If that's not the case, I'd suggest changing the service type for your APIs services to ClusterIP.

Comment: They are already ClusterIP, but we have ingress controller which redirects to a specific service based on path, and that makes APIs accessible from outside of the cluster. I tried changing the website to call internal clusterip for each service, but there is a problem with mixed content server. Website use https, where each internal cluster service is server over http.

Comment: If you're using NGINX as an ingress controller, there is an annotation to whitelist a specific range of IPs https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#whitelist-source-range

Comment: So are you suggesting to add SPA service IP address to the whitelist and other external requests will be ignored?